# Generate Random Number in Pyscript

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pyscript

I have created this file sample.py:

https://pastebin.com/KLsRqumV

and then I created this file in HTML, in which I inserted py-script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <title>PyScript Tags</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />

    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

    <py-env>
        -paths:
            -/sample.py
    </py-env>
  </head>

  <body>
     <br>
    Alcuni elementi di esempio da utilizzare in Pyscript:
<strong>Stampa numeri random tramite il recupero del file random.py</strong>
<b>Il numero fortunato è <label id="random"></label></b>
<py-script>
    from sample import generate_random_number
    pyscript.write('random', generate_random_number())
</py-script>

  </body>
</html>
```

But don't show any random number.

Through DevTools by Chrome I see this alert:
[image]

I use VS Code and add on 'Go Live', and reload the Chrome page when I edit HTML code.
I noticed that HTML code and sample.py are on the same path. what could be the problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: 1) How are you serving your application (reading from a file or via a web server)? 2) Open the browser debugger and post the error messages in your question.

Comment: this code works for me only when I run it on web server. It can be even local server like `python -m http.server`. I found your `generate_random_number()` in article [How to Use PyScript – A Python Frontend Framework](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pyscript-python-front-end-framework/) and it has line `"Tip: If you're using the VSCode editor, you can use the Live Server add-on in VSCode to reload the page as you update the HTML file."` which may suggest author also uses some kind of web server

Comment: @JohnHanley If I debugger with browser I obtain this alert: -base.ts:148 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')
    at PyScript.evaluate ; and - Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received - I run this code in vs code through 'Go live' with chrome

Comment: @furas, yah I use Vs code, and use GoLive to control html+python code when I edit

Comment: Please edit your question with those details and not as comments.

Comment: it has to run as page on server. Browser has to start it using url `http:// ...`. If you start it in as local file `file:// ...` then it gives this error. All because of security system in browser and you can't change it.

Comment: @furas ok, so I can insert html + python code in a web page (for example) and I obtain results? Or there will be error for a not compatibility with python? (Think that not all hosting are compatibility with python)

Comment: you can test it locally using `python -m http.server`. But it should work on any web server because it doesn't run Python on server but it uses JavaScript in browser to run it.

Comment: I resolved, I did edit file with code from this link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pyscript-python-front-end-framework/ - so, I can view the result if I use code in vs code and in a web site. Probably I wrong something, but in this moment I don't know what

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the syntax of the configuration inside `py-env`. It is a YAML configuration. after "-" you should have 1 space character

```
<py-env>
  - paths:
    - /sample.py
  </py-env>
```

Then `pyscript.write` will throw this error:"in write AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'innerHTML' ". `pyscript` is new, experimental, its api will be changing so often.

To use `.write` function and you need to select a DOM element and `.write` will set is `innerHTML`. Pyscript has global `Element` class, which allows you to get an HTML element by its ID. So you can create a div element and change its `innerHTML` or you can even console it:

```
<div id="random" >
  </div>
  <py-env>
  - paths:
    - /sample.py
  </py-env>
  <py-script  >
    from sample import generate_random_number
    from js import console
    # get element by id with global Element
    random=Element("random")
    random.write(f"random: {generate_random_number()} ")
    console.log('random--------------------', generate_random_number())
</py-script>
```